# LimitToFirst in Firebase (Unity)

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

Currently developing an application in Unity wherein I need to get the top 3 products that are being used. I am using the code below in retrieving data:

```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
        .GetReference ("Products").OrderByChild("used").LimitToFirst(3)
        .ValueChanged += HandleValueChanged;
    }

    void HandleValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args) {
    if (args.DatabaseError != null) {
        Debug.LogError (args.DatabaseError.Message);
        return;
    }
```

It is not working, I am receiving this error:

`System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at ShowProducts.HandleValueChanged (System.Object sender, Firebase.Database.ValueChangedEventArgs args) [0x000be] in C:\Users\jorren\Documents\JKL\Assets\Scripts\ShowProducts.cs:697 
  at Firebase.Database.Internal.Core.ValueEventRegistration.FireEvent (Firebase.Database.Internal.Core.View.DataEvent eventData) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Firebase.Database.Internal.Core.View.DataEvent.Fire () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Firebase.Database.Internal.Core.View.EventRaiser+Runnable30.Run () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Firebase.Database.DotNet.DotNetPlatform+SynchronizationContextTarget+<PostEvent>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 (System.Object x) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Firebase.Unity.UnitySynchronizationContext+SynchronizationContextBehavoir+<Start>c__Iterator0.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Firebase.Unity.<Start>c__Iterator0:MoveNext()
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)`

But when I use LimitToLast(), it is working fine

Big thanks!

Comment: This is a common `NullReferenceException` which could mean that there aren less than 3 Products in your Database.

Comment: There are 4 products in my database :(

Comment: Check with the debugger if `.GetReference ("Products").OrderByChild("used")` returns all 4 of your products. Maybe some filter criteria is preventing from returning all.

Comment: I got the same error when i tried .GetReference ("Products").OrderByChild("used")

Comment: So the `FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance` is NULL?

Comment: no, when i tried .GetReference ("Products").OrderByChild("used").EqualTo("11") it worked also

Comment: Please provide the `inner exception` of your error. I'm still not sure what exactly is `null` in this constellation.

Comment: I edited my question above

Comment: What is this line in your code?
C:\Users\jorren\Documents\JKL\Assets\Scripts\ShowProducts.cs:697

This is null ref'ing in your code -- in your ValueChanged callback.